# NUnit: Method taking multiple arguments instead of 1 string array

Tags: c#, nunit

I am trying to run the following test and use some data from a Json file.  The data here I am trying to use is an array of strings.  When I run the test I get the error:  Too many arguments provided, provide at most 1 arguments.

The data seems to be coming into the method as multiple arguments instead of 1 array of strings.  How can I solve this?

```
[Test, TestCaseSource(nameof(RolesData))]
public void CheckRoles(string[] rolesData)
{
   for(int i = 0; i < rolesData.Length; i++)
   {
     .WriteLine(rolesData[i]);
   }
}

public static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> RolesData()
{
    yield return new TestCaseData(GetDataParser().ExtractDataArray("name"));
}
```

The method used to extract the data is here:

```
public String[] ExtractDataArray(String tokenName)
{
  String myJsonString = File.ReadAllText("../../../Test Data/Login.json");
  var jsonObject = JToken.Parse(myJsonString);
  List<String> roleList =  jsonObject.SelectTokens(tokenName).Values<String>().ToList();
  return roleList.ToArray();
}
```

My Json file is like this:

```
{
  "username1": "dev@dev.com",
  "password1": "test123",

  "name": [
    "Manage Roles",
    "Edit Training",
    "View Users",
    "ViewAudit",
    "Manage OU",
    "View Groups",
    "ViewAudit",
    "ManageConfiguration",
    "View Analytics"
  ]
}
```

I am using NUnit v 3.13.3

Attempted fix:

```
    public static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> RolesData() 
    {     
       yield return new TestCaseData(new[] { "name" }); 
    }
```

Comment: try removing `yield`.

Comment: If I remove yield then I get Error CS0266 - Cannot implicitly convert type 'type1' to 'type2'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Answer (score 2):

One constructor for TestCaseData takes a params array, which is supposed to represent the list of arguments to the test method. In your case, the array is not a list of arguments but is actually the first (and only) argument.

So, to conform with this constructor, you have to pass an array whose first (and only) member is the array you want used as an argument. Awkward, I know!

For example, if your string array containing roles is `roles`, then create

```
new TestCaseData(new [] { roles } );
```

Comment: Thank you for this.  So in my example code how would this be added - in the return line of RolesData() method?  My string array is called "names".

Comment: I have tried the fix shown above in the question but I receive an error System.ArgumentException : Object of type 'System.String' cannot be converted to type 'System.String[]'

Comment: You added a string "name" ... that is with the letters n, a, m and e. If your array is called `names`, then add an array containing that array, just as shown in my answer, but replacing `roles` with `names`.